# Debian SSH cant sudo

Tags: ssh, debian, sudo

i have a Debian Server which only can be accessed remotely via SSH.
And i have a Couplet of Problems.

When i try to login as `root` it does not accept my password.

When i am logged in as normal user i cant `sudo` because it also does not accept my password.

But when i try `su` it works.

And commands Like reboot are Not round. But this can be solved by exporting /sbin to $Path in the .bashrc file. Right?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! It's best if you focus on 1 question at the time, e.g. how to run `sudo` on your debian server. Secondly, it's necessary to show some research in your question. What have you looked into already? Any websearches you've done? Config files you've looked into? Please [edit] your question to include your research and to focus on 1 question.

Comment: By "my password", do you mean "my regular user's password"? or "root's password"?

Comment: I have tried both. And i will edit my questuion with all requested details in 3 weeks, when i am back to work.